# What is the number of integer solutions of the inequality : $\sin x \cos x + \frac12 \tan x \ge 1\;,x\in [ -\pi , \pi ]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Q )   $\sin x \cos x + \frac12 \tan x \ge 1\;,x\in [ -\pi , \pi ]$ . Find the number of integral solutions .**

**My solving so far :**

$$ 1/2 \sin 2x  + 1/2  \tan x  \ge 1 \Rightarrow \tan^3 x - 2 \tan^2 x + 3 \tan x - 2 \ge 0 $$

Taking $\tan x = y$

$$( y - 1 ) ( y^2 - y + 2 ) \ge 0 \Rightarrow ( y - 1 ) \ge 0.$$  since $( y^ 2 - y + 2 )$ is always positive.

$y = \tan x\ge 1$

**How do I proceed next ?**

**OR HELP ME UNDERSTAND THE BOOK's SOLUTION** ( D )

[image]

Comment: Is your inequality $ \ge 1$ or $ \ge 0$

Comment: if your inequality is $ \ge 1$, then $tanx \ge 1$ and the only integer in $[-\pi \: \pi]$ for which $tanx \gt 1$ is $x=1$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma up its >= 1 , you mean to say tan 1 ( radian ) = 1 ?

Comment: Ok please edit your headline, it says $\ge 0$. ya $1$ i mean $1$ radian

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Is that small angle approximation ?

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma The book says the answer is 2 .

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma The book has given a solution , but I dont understand wht it does , should i post the picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah fine its two integers possible for $tanx \gt 1$ in $[-\pi \: \pi]$ which are $x=-2$ and $x=1$

Comment: it will be clearly evident when you draw $tanx$ graph. btw the image you posted has a different question?

Comment: How to find -2 & 1 without calculator ?

Comment: since $tanx$ is increasing in $(0 \: \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $tan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1$ obviously there is one integer in $(\frac{\pi}{4} \: \frac{\pi}{2}) =(\frac{11}{14} \: \frac{11}{7})$ for which $tanx \gt 1$. The only integer in $(\frac{11}{14} \: \frac{11}{7})$ is $1$. Same is applicable for negative side where you get $x=-2$

Comment: Awesome . Thank You .